$\Gamma(\operatorname{Spec}\mathcal{O}_{S,s},R^{p}f_{*}\mathcal{F}) = (R^{p}f_{*}\mathcal{F})_{\mathfrak{m}_s}$?
Consider a proper morphism of schemes of the form $f: X\to Y=\operatorname{Spec}\mathcal{O}_{S,s}$, where $S$ is a locally noetherian scheme. Let $\mathfrak{m}_s \subseteq \mathcal{O}_{S,s}$ be the maximal ideal. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a coherent $\mathcal{O}_X$-module. Then,
$$\Gamma(\operatorname{Spec}\mathcal{O}_{S,s},R^{p}f_{*}\mathcal{F}) = (R^{p}f_{*}\mathcal{F})_{\mathfrak{m}_s}$$
( the right hand side is the stalk ) ? If so, why?

What is the meaning of the LHS?

The global section of $R^{p}f_{*}\mathcal{F}$ over $\operatorname{Spec}\mathcal{O}_{S,s}$.

Let $\mathcal{G} := R^{p}f_{*}\mathcal{F}$ and $M:= \Gamma(Y,\mathcal{G})$. Then $\mathcal{G}$ is coherent by https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02O5.  So, it is quasi-coherent and $\mathcal{G} \cong \tilde{M}$. So,
$$\Gamma(\operatorname{Spec}\mathcal{O}_{S,s},R^{p}f_{*}\mathcal{F})=\Gamma(Y,\mathcal{G})=:M \cong M_{\mathfrak{m}_s} = \tilde{M}_{\mathfrak{m}_s} = ( R^{p}f_{*}\mathcal{F})_{\mathfrak{m}_s}$$
, where the middle isomorphism is true by next lemma :

Lemma : Let $A$ be a local ring with maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$. Let $M$ be an $A$-module. Then $M \cong M_{\mathfrak{m}} $ as $A$-modules.

$\because$ Define $f: M \to M_{\mathfrak{m}}$ by $f(m):=\frac{m}{1}$. This is well defined module homomorphism.

Injectivity : Assume $\frac{m}{1}=\frac{0}{1}$. Then there exists $u\in A-\mathfrak{m}$ such that $u(m-0)=0$. Since $u$ is invertible ( here we use that $A$ is local ), so $m=0$.

Surjectivity : Fix $\frac{m}{s}\in M_{\mathfrak{m}}$. Then $ s\in A-\mathfrak{m}$ so $s$ is invertible. Since $\frac{m}{s}=\frac{s^{-1}m}{1}$, we have that $f$ is surjective.


So we are done.
